# Liquibase vs settingsKey

Tags: maven, passwords, settings, liquibase

I would like to use settingsKey in my pom.xml setup to launch liquibase.
There is any way to use it ?

I have made several test but each time I have the same issue:

```
Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I have correctly set a master password in my: **settings-security.xml**

```
<settingsSecurity>
  <master>{/yLlt6y5Y+UH21v.........../aNaKOjAQ=}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

I have correctly set my server in my: **settings.xml**

```
<server>
  <id>server.dbA350025Test</id>
  <username>A350025</username>
  <password>{+WkbuHjo4BMHQ..........6EQ9X4CJaDZqw=}</password>
</server>
```

I have correctly set key **settingsKey** in my maven plugin setup: **pom.xml**

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <propertyFile>target/classes/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    <settingsKey>server.dbA350025Test</settingsKey>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <changeLogFile>liquibase_ng/main_changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    <goals>
    <goal>update</goal>
    </goals>
    </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
```

**And my properties file is correctly set:**

```
driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@ngc...01:1522:NG..01
verbose: true
dropFirst: false
```

In my case I am using also the filtering, but I try without the filtering there is no change.

If someone know if it is possible to use encrypted password to connect to database with maven liquibase plugin I will be very happy.

**For information:**

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
<version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Full error message:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:update (default) on project sql: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:update (default) on project sql: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Regards,

Comment: When I google for "maven settingsKey" the first result lead a page from mojohouse and a plugin called "sql-maven-plugin". 
Are you maybe mixing things? I think the liquibase maven plugin does not have an attribute "settingsKey". I guess that is the reason why it is not picking up your user/pass at all...

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was thinking the same thing , but I hopped there is someone who have done the same type of things and have a solution to secure password for maven liquibase plugin.

Comment: You're welcome. 
When you are looking for a way to secure your password you should rephrase your question - or make a new question. 
Checkout this ticket in liquibase Jira: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1932